# Positioning a Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css, header, navigation

[Screenshot: Current Homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHOyI.png)

[Screenshot: Desired Homepage / Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTKtM.png)

[Screenshot: Footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIadC.png)

I am trying to position a Dropdown Nav Bar within the Header below one of two images.

Currently, the nav bar is floated to the left, as this was how we were taught to do it in class so far, but both images within the header ('Logo' & 'Online Portfolio Banner') are also floated left. I'm wondering if there is a way to achieve my desired homepage look, with the Nav bar placed beneath the banner?

Code Snippet:

```css
nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
nav ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    min-width: 150px;
    padding: 7px 4px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-color: #393939;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #2cc1d9;
}
nav ul ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
nav ul ul li {
    float: none;
}
nav ul ul li a {
    background-color: rgba(108,210,221,1.00);
    min-width: 200px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: .8em;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #393939;
}
nav ul li:hover ul {
    left: 0px;
}
img {
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
}
.banner {
    width: 585px;
    height: 77px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p><img src="images/logo.png" width="130" height="130" alt="image of brand logo"></p>
  <p>
  <div class="banner"><img src="images/OP_header.png" width="585" height="77" alt="online portfolio banner"></div>
  </p>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
          <li><a href="resume.html">My Resume</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Work</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="branding.html">Identity & Branding</a></li>
          <li><a href="typography.html">Typography</a></li>
          <li><a href="marketing.html">Marketing</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or work-arounds? I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: do use using simple HTML5 or any Frame work

Comment: @Launren, you have used float:left, which make nav to sit beside banner, if you need to start nav from next, use clear:both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've structured this wrong, Try this (*use full screen for preview*):

```css
nav {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
}

nav ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
}

nav ul li {
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
}

nav ul li a {
 display: block;
 min-width: 150px;
 padding: 7px 4px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 background-color: #393939;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
 color: #2cc1d9;
}
nav ul ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: -9999px;
}
nav ul ul li {
 float: none;
}
nav ul ul li a {
 background-color: rgba(108,210,221,1.00);
 min-width: 200px;
 color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 display: block;
 padding: 7px 2px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: .8em;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover {
 color: #393939;
}
nav ul li:hover ul {
 left: 0px;
}
.brand-logo {
 padding: 10px;
 float: left;
}
.banner {
  padding: 10px;
 width: 585px;
 height: 77px;
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="brand-logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/130x130" width="130" height="130" alt="image of brand logo">
  </div>
  <div class="banner">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/585x77" width="585" height="77" alt="online portfolio banner">
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
          <li><a href="resume.html">My Resume</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Work</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="branding.html">Identity &amp; Branding</a></li>
          <li><a href="typography.html">Typography</a></li>
          <li><a href="marketing.html">Marketing</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Its my pleasure @LaurenMarie

Comment: There is one other issue I'm having and I'm not sure if you could help me with it, but I can't get my footer to stay at the bottom of the web page...it appears, but seems to float above my wrapper div, leaving a lot of space between it and the bottom of the browser window.

In the css, I've positioned the footer to absolute, while the width is set to 100%. In the html, I've placed the footer tags just after the closing wrapper div...are any one of those causing this issue? 

ps - I'm not sure if I can place code in a comment...

Comment: I've added another screenshot so you can see what I'm describing. 
See: Screenshot Footer

Answer (score 1):

```css
nav{
clear:both
}

nav ul {
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
}
nav ul li {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
nav ul li a {
 display: block;
 min-width: 150px;
 padding: 7px 4px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 background-color: #393939;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
 color: #2cc1d9;
}
nav ul ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: -9999px;
}
nav ul ul li {
 float: none;
}
nav ul ul li a {
 background-color: rgba(108,210,221,1.00);
 min-width: 200px;
 color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 display: block;
 padding: 7px 2px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: .8em;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover {
 color: #393939;
}
nav ul li:hover ul {
 left: 0px;
}
img {
 margin-top: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
 float: left;
}
.banner {
 width: 585px;
 height: 77px;
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p><img src="images/logo.png" width="130" height="130" alt="image of brand logo"></p>
  <p>
  <div class="banner"><img src="images/OP_header.png" width="585" height="77" alt="online portfolio banner"></div>
  </p>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
          <li><a href="resume.html">My Resume</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Work</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="branding.html">Identity & Branding</a></li>
          <li><a href="typography.html">Typography</a></li>
          <li><a href="marketing.html">Marketing</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```